# CMS build with Django, which requires no coding

Tags: cms, django

Required features:

- open source
- CMS, which does not require coding for the common use cases
- mobile friendly pages
- uses django under the hood
- active community

Answer (score 1):

[CodeRed](https://www.coderedcorp.com/cms/python-django-bootstrap-cms/) looks like it fits all requirements.

But I have not used it myself up to now.

Build with:

- Django
- Wagtail
- Bootstrap4
- Draftail (WYSIWYG Editor)

Answer (score 0):

[Puput](https://github.com/APSL/puput)

> A Django blog app implemented in Wagtail